# I have a nice image hover effect on desktop, but it gets stuck on hovered in mobile (Codepen included)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, hover

https://codepen.io/DubCoder/pen/poEQJap  I really like this hover effect on desktop, but when I show my friends my site on mobile, they touch the image, and it enlarges/colorizes, but then it stays in that state, even after they touch it again. It only goes back to it's original black and white state after they scroll away from it.

I would like the photo to toggle between the two states each time you touch it on mobile. I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm sure there's a way to use media queries or JS to recognise when the user is on a mobile, and add/remove the colored state on click.

I think the fact there's pseudo-classes involved may make it trickier.

```css
body {
  background-color: beige
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5rem;
  top: 2rem;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) rotate(3deg);
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.polaroid {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.polaroid>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item .polaroid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.item .polaroid:before {
  height: 20%;
  width: 47%;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item:hover {
  filter: none;
  transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg) !important;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.item:hover .polaroid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  height: 90%;
  width: 75%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="polaroid">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YVg9Ru.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:hover` behavior doesn’t exist on touch screen devices ?

Comment: Works for me on mobile man - after I click somewhere else outside the image it reverts!

Comment: @MiloshN. hover is emulated on most touchscreen devices by a long press.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making it focusable. It won't be a toggle by pressing just it, but it will still act natural as to what the user would expect and will be much easier to add.

You can do it by adding `tabindex="0"` to `.item` in the HTML markup. Then replace the two lines:

```
.item:hover {
```

```
.item:hover .polaroid:before {
```

with

```
.item:hover, .item:focus {
```

```
.item:hover .polaroid:before, .item:focus .polaroid:before {
```

This will apply the effect when it's focused too. You might want to add

```
outline: none
```

Inside the `.item:hover, .item:focus` class to remove the black outline on focus.

Your final results might be:

```css
body {
  background-color: beige
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5rem;
  top: 2rem;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) rotate(3deg);
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.polaroid {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.polaroid>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item .polaroid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.item .polaroid:before {
  height: 20%;
  width: 47%;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item:hover, .item:focus {
  outline: none;
  filter: none;
  transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg) !important;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.item:hover .polaroid:before, .item:focus .polaroid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  height: 90%;
  width: 75%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" tabindex="0">
  <div class="polaroid">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YVg9Ru.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a toggle, you'll need to use JS. I'm simply adding and removing a `active` class from the element on click and then using it in place of an event.

I removed the hover effect so you can see it better on PC.

```js
function toggleClass(ele, className) {
  if (ele.classList.contains(className)) {
    ele.classList.remove(className);
  } else {
    ele.classList.add(className);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: beige
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5rem;
  top: 2rem;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) rotate(3deg);
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.polaroid {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.polaroid>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item .polaroid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.item .polaroid:before {
  height: 20%;
  width: 47%;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item.active {
  outline: none;
  filter: none;
  transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg) !important;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.item.active .polaroid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  height: 90%;
  width: 75%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" onclick="toggleClass(this, 'active')">
  <div class="polaroid">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YVg9Ru.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is still not quite what I'm looking for. I was hoping there was a way to toggle the effect on/off on mobiles, just by tapping on it.

Comment: @McSha8, ok, I think the only way to do that is with a bit of JavaScript

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! (Upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation for it to count!)

Comment: @McSha8, Thanks fine. If it answered your question you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark by the vote count